# Rotating a view on Android issue

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments, layout, rotation

I have been stuck on quite an irritating problem for a number of days now.

To describe the problem; I essentially have a issue when I perform a rotation on a view which is part of a larger view, then I display a fragment on top of this view, and then hide this fragment returning to the original view.

The view maintains its rotation but is placed above and to the right of where it should be.

In the XML layout I have set the view to be centered in the parent, and sure enough on startup everything is where its supposed to be.

While the view is rotating and the main view is visible (it is essentially a compass) everything works as intended

If I do not rotate the view, then show the fragment followed by hiding it it stays where it was meant to be without issue, so clearly the act of rotating it and then displaying something over it is causing a problem.

If I continue to rotate the view after it has moved out of position, it snaps back into its centered position and all is well - how can I ensure the view to always remain where its suppose to be?!?

For reference I am calling the rotation method like so:

```
RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(PREVOIUS_ROTATION_AMOUNT, NEW_ROTATION, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f); 
rotate.setDuration(980);
rotate.setRepeatCount(0); 
rotate.setFillAfter(true);
compassView.startAnimation(rotate);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should do what you're expecting:

```
compassView.setPivotX(compassView.getMeasuredWidth() / 2);
compassView.setPivotY(compassView.getMeasuredHeight() / 2);
compassView.animate().rotation(NEW_ROTATION).setDuration(980);
```

Comment: Thanks Gil, I just tried this suggestion and the behaviour is exactly the same as I originally experienced. Its almost like the rotation points are lost and the view is rotating around x=compassView.getMeasuredWidth() / 2 ,y=0

Comment: what is compassView? A View? A LinearLayout?

Comment: CompassView is a RelativeLayout

Comment: and how are you measuring the RelativeLayout? what dimensions did you give it?

Comment: It is constructed in XML, using  Align right/left/Bottom against another view (the other view is set to wrap content and contains an image)

Comment: As an experiment, I nested the RelativeLayout in a LinearLayout and rotated the LinearLayout instead, the behaviour is identical.

Comment: does getMeasuredHeight() return the correct value? If so, then this code should work, and its likely that there is some other code elsewhere which is influencing the pivot point of the rotation.

Comment: aha, I notice that getMeasuredHeight() returns 0 when a fragment is visible, and a positive number (636 for completeness) the fact it returns 0 is no doubt the problem...but how do I stop this from happening, and why does it return 0?!

Comment: you must perform the animation only AFTER a measurement has occurred.  One option would be to override the onMeasure method, and perform the animation after the call to the super.onMeasure. You'd probably want to only do this once, so you could use a boolean flag to indicate that the animation occurred and doesn't need to happen again.

Comment: hmmm, it looks like that is the way to do it. I will investigate and see what I can do, thanks for all your help so far.

Comment: Ok, so after a bit of thought I decided that in this particular instance - (mainly because there is only one animation occurring) that I would simply check in the animating method if the result of getMeasuredHeight() was 0, and if it was to not animate. This has resolved the issue and i'm very thankful for your help in getting there!